Chrome extensions unable to read the methods of the 'sessions' API
I am trying to develop an extension that will take tabs from one session and open them in another session. To do this I am using chrome's sessions API.
However, when I run any code such as: chrome.sessions.getDevices().then((devices) => {...}
I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDevices')
This has happened with every single method that I have tried from the sessions API, and I have the following permissions in my manifest file:
"permissions": [
      "sessions",
      "tabs",
      "gcm",
      "contentSettings",
      "history",
      "identity",
      "processes",
      "search",
      "system.memory"
    ],

What could be the issue here?

Can u give a code that I can reproduce. If you are using manifest v2, you can't use promise like this.
